# Bash -v test doesn't work with associative arrays in 4.3.46

Tags: bash, set, associative-array

The `-v` unary operator that was introduced in version 4.2 to test if a variable is set or not does not appear to work in bash 4.3.46 on associative arrays.

I have some bash test code that I run against a set of bash functions, and they all pass in bash 4.2 (on CentOS 7.1).  I recently booted up a Lubuntu 16.04.1 distro and noticed a good portion of my tests now failed, with bash 4.3.46.  It seems like all of the failures are due to code like this:

```
function is_var_set {
    local var="${1:?"No var provided to 'is_var_set'!"}"
    [[ -v "$var" ]]
}

declare -A array=(["a"]="element 1")
is_var_set "array"
```

Is this a widely known thing/was support removed for associative arrays?

Comment: It fails with indexed arrays too (4.3.42). The bug was probably introduced when support for `-v array[subscript]` was added, as previously that always failed whether the entry existed or not, and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current [bash manual on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) says

> An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value.

So IMHO, you'd have to do something different for associative arrays. I can't tell if this is a recent change in bash behavior.

Another way to define `is_var_set` would be to (ab)use the [`declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins), using the following:

> The return status is zero unless ... one of the names is not a valid shell variable name ...

```
function is_var_set {
  declare -p "${1:?"No var provided to 'is_var_set'! "}" &> /dev/null
}
```

The above would work for top-level variable names, but not for any particular array elements.

Comment: Thanks, I do have the `declare -p` in use in some code, as well as the `${var+x}` trick.  I guess I'm just wondering if this changed or if it is a bug, and the bash manual does mention subscripts when talking about associative arrays.  So it seems to me that assigning a value to a non-integer subscript in an associative array would satisfy the condition you quoted.

Comment: associative arrays can use integers as subscripts/indexes as well!

Comment: Yes, they can :) But do you agree that assigning *anything* to an associative array qualifies as having assigned a subscript a value? By that, it seems `-v` should work.  I guess to clarify, it seems that your answer implies you don't agree, since you said *So IMHO, you would have to do something different for associative arrays.*

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood you before -- yes, that's true. It seems that bash doesn't do it that way -- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/test.c#n633 -- seems to look for indexed arrays (or maybe assoc. ones with a value at key '0')

Answer (score 3):

In bash version 4.3.46 **only**      (older versions (4.2) do not understand this syntax and newer versions do not have this problem).

You need to test an array, not (only) the element 0.

```
[[ -v array[@] ]]
```

This fails:

```
$ declare -A array=(["a"]="element 1")
$ declare -p array
declare -A array=([a]="element 1" )

$ [[ -v array ]] && echo yes            # nothing is printed.
```

But this works:

```
$ [[ -v array[@] ]] && echo yes
yes
```

So change you function to:

```
function is_var_set {
    local avar="${1:?"No var provided to 'is_var_set'!"}[@]"
    [[ -v "$avar" ]]
}
```

Test it with this script:

```
function is_var_set {
    local avar="${1:?"No var provided to 'is_var_set'!"}[@]"
    [[ -v "$avar" ]] && echo "$1 set: yes" || echo "$1 set: no"
    echo
}

var=wer
echo "array scalar $(declare -p var)"
is_var_set var

var=( foo bar baz )
echo "var indexed array $(declare -p var)"
is_var_set var

unset var
echo "var associative array $(declare -p var)"
is_var_set var

declare -A var=(["a"]="element 1")
echo "var associative array $(declare -p var)"
is_var_set var

declare -A var=(["a"]="")
echo "var associative array $(declare -p var)"
is_var_set var
```

Comment: This approach fails for this case: `declare -A array=([a]=""); [[ -v array[@] ]] && echo yes` results in no output. Expected result: "yes".

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Since it works with all versions of bash above 4.3 and I carry no more the version 4.3.46  I can not reproduce your problem (it works correctly in 4.3.48). It would be wise to update bash (there are several security issues on old versions).

Comment: Your solution does indeed work. I forgot I had installed a test build of bash a few months ago. After installing the proper bash distributed with my linux distribution, I get the expected "yes" from the test in my previous comment.